# custom catcomplete doesnt show results when contain multiple categories

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

`enter code here`I am trying to reproduce the search suggestion in facebook.  That it shows on the same box results of different 'types' with a header (persones, groups, pages, ..)

Basically i need to group the results by type and add a non-cliclable header with the name of the type (example: user, group); Just like facebook does:

[image]

This is the custom catcomplete from jquery ui page:

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
                                _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
                                    var self = this,
                                        currentCategory = "";
                                        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                                            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                                                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                                                currentCategory = item.category;
                                            }
                                            self._renderItem( ul, item );
                                        });
                                }
                            });
```

-EDIT-

Can be tested here by typing 'bootcamp' on the serch field (no need to login): http:// 209.51.221.243/integracion/login.php   (type 'deya' works, type 'bootcamp' doesn't work

Wich is working fine when is only one type of results, but when there are more than one, like in this response:

```
[{"value":"Donde puedo descargar los drivers de bootcamp?","id":"1","category":"Ayudas"}][{"value":"Donde puedo descargar los drivers de bootcamp?","id":"1","category":"Ayudas"},{"first_name":"bootcamp","last_name":"bootcamp","id":"95","value":"bootcamp bootcamp","category":"Usuarios"}]
```

it doesn't show any ressult, why?

Comment: what is your problem? Your code look ok. What's not working?

Comment: well that's the thing, it works as expected. it shows returning items in the autocomplete list. what i am trying to add is a header letting users know that netxt items are of that type (example: persones, groups, pages, ..)

Comment: so your question is how to style it with css?

Comment: well as i am tring to explain in my question ( i made an edit ), i dont know how to add the needed html elements that represents the type, also; how to group them by type

Comment: Have you seen http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3820/trunk/demos/autocomplete/categories.html?

Comment: @j08691 riight! i didn't need to alter render_item but render_list, this looks like better procedure. thanks a lot, post it as an answer if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php only add the sub, for the 1st row of each type.
You can do that with a global variable:

```
$first = array();

while (...) {
   if (!$first[$row['type']]) {
       $first[$row['type']] = true;
       $row['sub'] = $row['type'];
   }
}
```

then in your javascript:

```
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            var sub = "";
            if (item.sub) {
                sub = $("<li class="sub">" + item.sub + "</li>");
                ul.append(li);
            }
            var li = $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a><img src='"+item.img+"' /><span class='name'>" + item.value + "</span></a>" )
            ul.append(li);
                        };
```

Comment: hey! thanks for your post. i just made an edit, it easier to understand with the screen to achieve

Comment: i see i just append an li with no link! that was easier than i thought!, but i don't understand the !$first logic..

Comment: my logic for the first thing was this: you only want the "empty li" before the FIRST row of the X rows of that type, but it's easier to know it in php, although the same loginc would work with some global variable in javascript as well. $first is an associative array, and once you encounter a type (that is the 1st element of that type) you set it, so next time you see that type (2nd row of the same type) you don't add another empty li. This solution BTW depends on that your mysql will sort the results in a way that the same types come one after the other and not mixed

Comment: I see, you mean doing that so i don't need to worry in the client side? but i think i do any way, because i need to apply different class to the item..

Comment: ok, but the idea is the same: track in a global variable that you've already added the "empty li" for the header

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3820/trunk/demos/autocomplete/categories.html

```
$.extend($.ui.menu.prototype, {
    next: function() {
        this.move("next", ".ui-menu-item:first");
    },
    previous: function() {
        this.move("prev", ".ui-menu-item:last");
    },
    move: function(direction, edge) {
        if (!this.active) {
            this.activate(this.element.children(edge));
            return;
        }
        var next = this.active[direction + "All"]('.ui-menu-item').eq(0);
        if (next.length) {
            this.activate(next);
        } else {
            this.activate(this.element.children(edge));
        }
    }
});

$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
            if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
    }
});​

$(function() {
    var data = [
        { label: "anders", category: "" },
        { label: "andreas", category: "" },
        { label: "antal", category: "" },
        { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
        { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
        { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
        { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
        { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
        { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
    ];
    $('#search').catcomplete({
        source: data
    });
});
```

I almost forgot that I created a jsFiddle example of something quite similar a little while ago: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jF9Mj/)**.